# Resizing an ext4 partition in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a ext4 partition (as described on the shema) that I want to increase its size, but can I do that when I have the contiguous swap partition in red? GParted doesn't allow me to remove the swap partition (only to disable it) to recreate. How should I proceed to increase the size of sda2?

[image]

Comment: The *lock* symbols show mounted partitions that can't be resized due to in-use.  Most *file-systems* can't be resized during operation, and you're not using any *fs* that can be.  It's best (*or at least easiest!*) to reboot into *live* media, so the *live* media (*thumb-drive*) is in-use, and you can resize partitions on your normal disk/ssd....

Comment: Three options. One resize. I might move swap to end and make smaller like 4GB. Check if UUID changes and update fstab if required.  Or create partition and use as /home. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Or create partition and use as data partiiton but leave /home with user settings in /. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk